# Read textfile and count number of Lines into Textbox using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

My objective is to read the textfile, manipulate the contents and display the result inside a listbox or listview

For example, a textfile has a content of multiple line grouped per date. What I need is to display the number of lines the textfile has into textbox

here's the sample textfile

[image]

**What I only have is to read the textfile using fileupload, button and Listbox and display all the content in it**

```
 protected void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (StreamReader stRead = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
        {
            //to write textfile content
            while (!stRead.EndOfStream)
            {
                ListBox1.Items.Add(stRead.ReadLine());
            }
        }



    }
```

**1. What can I do to count the lines in the textfile and display in textbox instead of listbox?**

Comment: Sorry, so what problem are you encountering?

Comment: use `TextBox1.Text += stRead.ReadLine();` to send the lines to the textbox and to count the lines, just use a simple counter variable in the while loop.

Comment: To read the lines you can simply do: `var lineCount = File.ReadLines(@"C:\file.txt").Count();`

Comment: Does ReadLine not just read in the text file one line at a time? if so, keep a count in the While loop and append each line read to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `TextBox` with `TextMode="MultiLine"` :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="multitxt" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Code behind:

```
string text = String.Empty;
using (StreamReader stRead = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
{
     int i = 0;
     //to write textfile content
     while (!stRead.EndOfStream)
     {
       text+=stRead.ReadLine()+Environment.NewLine;
       i++;
     }

 }

multitxt.Text = text;
```

`i` give you number of lines in txt file

You can always get number of lines

```
var file = stRead.ReadToEnd(); 
var allLines= file.Split(new char[] {'\n'});           
var count= lines.Count;
```

Or from `TextBox`

```
this.multitxt.Text.Split(new Char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
```

Comment: How about the counting part sir?

Comment: What you mean _counting part_?

Comment: the counting of lines

Comment: `i` give you counted lines

Comment: How about count the number of characters all in all in the textfile sir?

Comment: `multitxt.Text.Length` return number of characters in `TextBox`